# How to show deployment targets after run configuration in Android studio plugin

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I'm trying to create a plugin for Android Studio with a new run configuration following the guide [here](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/run_configurations.html), and I want to show the possible devices/emulators that the app can be deployed.

I'm at the step where `getState` is being called, but I'm not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rewriting my own Android Device picker by reading how the android plugin does it, using ddmlib (device listeners). For example: [AndroidDebugBridge.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/tools_r22/ddmlib/src/main/java/com/android/ddmlib/AndroidDebugBridge.java).